# Is accessing/recording internal audio possible on Android?

Tags: android, audio

I've researched this a bit and the only answers I've found just direct me to apps that kinda do it, and there's always some catch like it only working on Samsung phones etc. Nothing really relevant to development. What I mean by internal audio is audio coming out of the system, like the audio produced by a game for example. 
So is recording internal audio possible? If so, how would I go about implementing that?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Just curious, was I able to answer your question adequately? If not, please let me know so that I can help you come up with a solution if you haven't already. Otherwise, welcome to Stack Overflow and good luck !

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, it makes sense. I'd still like to figure out a way to actually record the output audio though, you said it wasn't possible using the API... do you know how I would be able to/if there's even any way to do that? Thank you!

Comment: I've edited my answer to include more detail on accessing the resources of the app. As mentioned before, this is hacky and is the only real solution to your question.

Comment: Thanks! But I was referring more to live recording, should've specified. So, I'm not intending to capture the isolated sound resources, but rather the sounds playing in real time. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Recording internal audio is possible, kind of..

[Android's](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html)
 API has MediaRecorder which allows for recording of microphone audio, so if internal audio is loud enough and the user agrees to the recording of the audio, then yes this is possible. But there is not direct way to do this via Android's API. Here is a snippet of some of their example [code](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html#example) for implementing this.

```
    `private void startRecording() {

         mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
         mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
         mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
         mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
         mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

         try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
         } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
         }
         mRecorder.start();
     }`
```

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder) has their version of audio recording for iPhone call AVAudioRecorder. But, again nothing built in for capturing internal audio by default, in their API atleast.

An alternative to recording the audio, is to locate the sound file from the app itself. But, [extracting the resources of an app](http://www.droidiser.com/2013/07/tip-extract-apk-get-sounds-pics.html) is not recommended and will most likely be in violation of your user agreement. The APK is basically a zip file of all of an applications resources in Android. Included in these resources, would be the sound. Like for example "the audio produced produced by a game" as you've stated in your question.

I hope this helps !